# I have question about how to prove probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For this question(see the image below), I am asked to prove probablity measure. I am confused that since the first two properties has already satastied probability measure. What should I do in this case? What should I prove about the third property?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAnYO.png)

Comment: (2) is given only for **finite** disjoint unions. You have to extend this to **countable** disjoint unions. Consider $\bigcap_{n\geq m} A_n$.

Comment: So, can I prove by this way:  for k from 1 to infinity, split it from 1 to n, and n+1  to infinity. Then analyze when k from n+1 to infinity. The union would be emplty, and the summation would be zero, then for (k = (1 to n) +(n+1 to infinity)) it is still equivalent? Therefore it is true for countable disjoint unions?